# how to use the logical operator "or"

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development

I am trying to implement a simple smart contract on Remix IDE (using Genache as my local blockchain)

Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Aa {

    uint public myuint;

    function set(uint _var) public {
            require(_var == 5 || 99, "Not 5 or 99!");
        myuint = _var;
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint){
        return myuint;
    }
}
```

I am getting an error: *"TypeError: Operator || not compatible with types bool and int_const 99
            require(_var == 5 || 99, "Not 5 or 99!");"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the question the code has an error on line:

```
require(_var == 5 || 99, "Not 5 or 99!");
```

This tells the compiler to compare ***_var == 5 and 99*** as opposed to comparing ***_var == 5 and _var == 99***

The correct code is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Aa {

    uint public myuint;

    function set(uint _var) public {
            require(_var == 5 || _var == 99, "Not 5 or 99!");
        myuint = _var;
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint){
        return myuint;
    }
}
```